# How to read appsettings.json in WPF Prism application

Tags: wpf, prism

In a pure WPF application I can use HostBuilder, like below. But how could I do the same in a Prism app? What I read, HostBuild is not possible in Prism (according to Brian Lagunas it would not make sense - cannot find the link).

Could someone point me to the right direction or share a code?

```
public App()
        {
            _host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configurationBuilder) =>
                {
                    configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
                    configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
                })
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.Configure<AppSettings>(context.Configuration);

                    services.AddDbContext<VisitorDbContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

                    services.AddScoped<ISampleService, SampleService>();
                    services.AddScoped<IImportService, ImportService>();
                    services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    //logging.AddConsole();
                })
                .Build();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the .NET host to parse the app settings, you could override the `RegisterTypes` method of your Prism `App.xaml.cs` class to register the `IOptions<T>` with the app:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    private readonly IHost _host;

    public App()
    {
        _host = ...;
    }

    ...

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(
           _host.Services.GetService<IOptions<AppSettings>>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't use the Host. According to Brian it does not make sense within Prism application.

Comment: So what is your question then? Your question reads "how could I do the same in a Prism app", doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly! As it is not recommended by Brian, I'm asking what is the preferred way to do it. I'll try to find Brian's statement regarding this.

Comment: Preferred way of doing what exactly? Parse a file?

Comment: Prism not supporting Generic Host https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/issues/63

Comment: What's your point (and question) ?

Answer (score 0):

Without using the host, this could be done like the following

```
public sealed partial class App
{
    private readonly AppSettings? _appSettings;

    public App()
    {
        IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection(typeof(AppSettings).Name));
        IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        IOptions<AppSettings>? options = provider.GetService<IOptions<AppSettings>>();
        if (options is null)
            throw new ApplicationException("App settings is not registered");

        _appSettings = options.Value;
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(_appSettings);
    }
}
```

you would need to add the following package

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.0" />
```

and the following namespaces

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
```